# Content-Security-Policy and problem with stand alone Js

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, content-security-policy

We would like to apply **Content-Security-Policy** and do not let inline Js or css.
As a result we are separating js and css into their own stand alone files.
However inside the aspx pages we have lots of razor syntax most of them are getting data from web.config. The problem that I have is, if we want to fully remove inline is and have stand alone one it is not possible.
Is there any way other than adding nonce that I can achieve this and access ViewData or a web.config info?

Is hidden element could be used?but that could be changed with developer tool..
application is .net mvc and the code is old so I have to work with what I have.
I am using VS2019 and the code was written in .net 3.5 just upgraded to be able to open in VS 2019 and it has not upgraded fundamentally.

Any help would be much appreciated!